# ResultSet.next() not selecting jPasswordField && jTextField

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement, resultset

Im creating a log in page at the moment however everytime I try to "login" I get the "Your username and password dont match" message even if the Username and password are valid and stored in the database. I can't figure this out at all even from other online resources as from what I can tell it should be working?

```
private void jButtonLoginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{                                             
    Connection con = myConnection.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement pscon;
    ResultSet rscon;

    try 
    {
        pscon = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * dbname.user WHERE 'username' = ? AND 'password' = ?");
        pscon.setString(1, jTextFieldUsername.getText());
        pscon.setString(2, String.valueOf(jPasswordFieldPass.getPassword()));
        rscon = pscon.executeQuery();

        if(rscon.next())
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Logged in successfully!");
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your username and password don't match!");
        }
    } 
    catch (SQLException ex) 
    {
        Logger.getLogger(LoginPage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sql is write incorrect,you need to remove the redundant `'` for `username` and `password` and add `FROM` keyword

So change

```
 pscon = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * dbname.user WHERE 'username' = ? AND 'password' = ?");
```

to

```
 pscon = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM dbname.user WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
```

or add ` to wrap the column name

```
 pscon = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM dbname.user WHERE `username` = ? AND `password` = ?");
```

Comment: Still missing FROM.

Comment: Perfect between the both of yous finally got this working! Thanks for your help, feel like an idiot been stuck for that long on that lol.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is wrong.

```
SELECT * dbname.user WHERE 'username' = ? AND 'password' = ?
```

should be

```
SELECT * FROM dbname.user WHERE 'username' = ? AND 'password' = ?
```

You missed "FROM". Also, you should not store unencrypted and unhashed passwords.

Comment: Realised that as I typed it but didn't solve the issue. Answer below by lucumt to remove " ' ' " from around username and password worked. Thanks for your reply though!